# Manipulating large quantities of data in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently working towards implementing a charting library with a database that contains a large amount of data. For the table I am using, the raw data is spread out across 148 columns of data, with over 1000 rows. As I have only created  models for tables that contain a few columns, I am unsure how to go about implementing a model for this particular table. My usual method of creating a model and using the Entity Framework to connect it to a database doesn't seem practical, as implementing 148 properties for each column does not seem like an efficient method.

My questions are:

What would be a good method to implement this table into an MVC project so that there are read actions that allow one to pull the data from the table?

How would one structure a model so that one could read 148 columns of data from it without having to declare 148 properties?

Is the Entity Framework an efficient way of achieving this goal?

Comment: What is being stored in these 148 columns?  Seems like maybe the first thing you should do is attempt to normalize the database schema.

Comment: Entity Framework isn't an efficient way of achieving or doing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Entity Framework Database First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx) sounds like the perfect solution for your problem.

Data first models mean how they sound; the data exists before the code does. Entity Framework will create the models as partial classes for you based on the table you direct it to.

Additionally, exceptions won't be thrown if the table changes (as long as nothing is accessing a field that doesn't exist), which can be extremely beneficial in a lot of cases. Migrations are not necessary. Instead, all you have to do is right click on the generated model and click "Update Model from Database" and it works like magic. The whole process can be significantly faster than Code First.

[Here is another tutorial](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/setting-up-database) to help you.

Answer (score 0):

yes with Database First you can create the entites so fast, also remember that is a good practice return onlye the fiedls that you really need, so, your entity has 148 columns, but your app needs only 10 fields, so convert the original entity to a model or viewmodel and use it!

One excelent tool that cal help you is [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's a lot of columns!

Given your circumstances a few thoughts come to mind:

**1:** If your problem is the leg work of creating that many properties you could look at [Entity Framework Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d/). EF Tools is able to reverse engineer a database and create the necessary models/entity relation mappings for you, saving you a lot of the grunt work.

To save you pulling all of that data out in one go you can then use projections like so:

```
var result = DbContext.ChartingData.Select(x => new PartialDto {
               Property1 = x.Column1,
               Property50 = x.Column50,
               Property109 = x.Column109
             });
```

A tool like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started) will allow you to do this with ease via simply configurable mapping profiles:

```
var result = DbContext.ChartingData.Project().To<PartialDto>().ToList();
```

**2:** If you have concerns with the performance of manipulating such large entities through Entity Framework then you could also look at using something like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) (which will happily work alongside Entity Framework).

This would save you the hassle of modelling the entities for the larger tables but allow you to easily query/update specific columns:

```
public class ModelledDataColumns
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    public string Property50 { get; set; }

    public string Property109 { get; set; }
}

const string sqlCommand = "SELECT Property1, Property50, Property109 FROM YourTable WHERE Id = @Id";
IEnumerable<ModelledDataColumns> collection = connection.Query<ModelledDataColumns>(sqlCommand", new { Id = 5 }).ToList();
```

Ultimately if you're keen to go the Entity Framework route then as far as I'm aware there's no way to pull that data from the database without having to create all of the properties one way or another.